# Fill DataGridView with DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I'm writting a program to fill a DataGridView, with a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn, using Linq, and I have found a problem. Now, my code is like this:

```
var files = from file in library.Descendants("File")
            where file.Element("Name").ToString().Contains(searchTerm)
            select new
                Selected = file.Element("Selected").Value,
                Name = file.Element("Name").Value,
                Size = file.Element("Size").Value)
            };
dataGridView1.DataSource = files.ToList();
```

I have declared the DataGridView column "Selected" as a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn and I have related the DataPropertyName with the Selected property. But, when I run the program, this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the Selected column is empty, even the checkboxes aren't presente.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot

**EDIT:** The xml data looks like this:

```
<Library>
  <File>
   <Selected>false</Selected>
   <Name>101-madonna-girl gone wild.mp3</Name>
   <Size>6338618</Size>
  </File>
  <File>
   <Selected>false</Selected>
   <Name>04 - Rock And Roll Music.mp3</Name>
   <Size>3693642</Size>
  </File>
</Library>
```

The Selected column definition is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the value as bool like this:

```
bool.Parse(file.Element("Selected").Value)
```

**EDIT:** Your code would look like this:

```
var files = from file in library.Descendants("File")
            where file.Element("Name").ToString().Contains(searchTerm)
            select new
            {
              Selected = bool.Parse(file.Element("Selected").Value),
              Name = file.Element("Name").Value,
              Size = file.Element("Size").Value)
            };
dataGridView1.DataSource = files.ToList();
```

Comment: How is your XML file look like? Could you post it?

Comment: @GabiCea, since you post your xml file as an answer (you shouldn't do that, insetd you had to edit your question and put it there), I wasn't  notified by the SO. Any how I've tested the query with you xml and everything was fine! note that you have to put an empty DateGridView on your form and just set its `DataSource` to your list.

Comment: @GabiCea, I edited your question ant put the xml there, please delete your posted answer.

Comment: I have post the Selected column definition, maybe, looking at it someone could help me, because I have tried running it more times, but the result is the same, not working succesfully

Answer (score 0):

Add one item template like the following

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
     <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and in the item template add the check box and after that use OnRowDataBound="GridViewRowEventHandler" to bind the check box value.